# Efficient data structure for the average of a sequence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to design a data structure that can support efficiently the following operations on a stored (as I see fit) sequence of numbers:

- Add the integer `x` to the first `i` elements of the sequence
- Append an integer `k` to the end of the sequence
- Remove the last element of the sequence
- Retrieve the average of all the elements in the sequence

#### Example

Starting with an empty sequence `[]`

- Append 0 (`[0]`)
- Append 5 (`[0, 5]`)
- Append 6 (`[0, 5, 6]`)
- Add 3 to the first 2 elements in the sequence (`[3, 8, 6]`)
- Retrieve the average 5.66 (`[3, 8, 6]`)
- Remove the last element (`[3, 8]`)
- Retrieve the average 5.5 (`[3, 8]`)

#### Previous work

I thought about using [Fenwick Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) ([Topcoder Editorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees)) but for that I would need to specify the maximum size of the sequence for the initialisation of the Fenwick tree which is don't necessarily know. But if I have a maximum number of elements that the sequence can support I can support those operations on `O(lg N)` if I also save the sum of all the elements in the sequence.

**Edit:** The question is for a [Codeforces problem](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/283/A) and I need sub-linear running time for all the operations and because adding to the first elements can be, in the worst case, be the same as adding to the whole sequence

Comment: What's this for? That first operation is unusual.

Comment: I am trying to solve a problem on [Codeforces](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/283/A) for some time now, but I could just use the tree but the solution was apparently too slow because of the array initialisation of the tree (I think)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered using a linked list plus the current length and sum? For each operation you can maintain the current average with constant extra work (you know the length of the list and the sum, and all operations change those two values in a constant way).

The only non-constant operation would be adding a constant to an arbitrary prefix, which would take time proportional to the size of the prefix since you'd need to adjust each number.

To make all operations constant (amortized) constant requires more work. Instead of using a doubly-linked list, back the array with a stack. Each slot `i` in the array now contains both the number at `i` and the constant that was to be added to every element up to `i`. (Note that if you say "add 3 to every element up to element 11," slot 11 would contain the number 3 but slots 0-10 would be empty.) Now every operation is as it was before, except that appending a new element involves the standard array-doubling trick, and when you pop the last element off the end of the queue you need to (a) add in the constant at that slot, and (b) add the constant value from slot `i` to the constant for slot `i-1`. So for your example:

Append 0:  `[(0,0)], sum 0, length 1`

Append 5:  `([(0,0),(5,0)], sum 5, length 2`

Append 6:  `[(0,0),(5,0),(6,0)], sum 11, length 3`

Add 3 to the first 2 elements in the sequence: `[(0,0),(5,3),(6,0)], sum 17, length 3`

Retrieve the average 5.66

Remove the last element `[(0,0),(5,3)], sum 11, length 2`

Retrieve the average 5.5

Remove the last element `[(0,3)], sum 3, length 1`

Here's some Java code that illustrates the idea perhaps more clearly:

```
class Averager {
  private int sum;
  private ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  private ArrayList<Integer> addedConstants = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public void addElement(int i) {
    elements.add(i);
    addedConstants.add(0);
    sum += i;
  }

  public void addToPrefix(int k, int upto) {
    addedConstants.set(upto, addedConstants.get(upto) + k);
    sum += k * (upto + 1);
    // Note: assumes prefix exists; in real code handle an error
  }

  public int pop() {
    int lastIndex = addedConstants.length() - 1;

    int constantToAdd = addedConstants.get(lastIndex);
    int valueToReturn = elements.get(lastIndex);
    addedConstants.set(
      lastIndex-1,
      addedConstants.get(lastIndex-1) + constantToAdd);
    sum -= valueToReturn;
    elements.remove(lastIndex);
    addedConstants.remove(lastIndex);
    return valueToReturn + constantToAdd;
    // Again you need to handle errors here as well, particularly where the stack
    // is already empty or has exactly one element
  }

  public double average() {
    return ((double) sum) / elements.length();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer if all operations are at least logarithmical since the prefix could be the length of a very big list. What would be the extra work to make it constant?

Comment: @GustavoTorres I may be missing something, but I don't see how adding something to `i` elements of the list could ever be less than `O(i)`

Comment: The trick is to do it lazily, relying on the fact that the only way to actually *observe* the values in the queue is to pop them off or take their average. See the code sample.

Comment: @jacobm very nice implementation! Simple and efficient! Thanks!

Comment: Interesting solution, although adding an item to the array list could take O(n) time (when it needs to grow). I wonder if that's counted . . .

Comment: Right, that's why I said amortized constant rather than true constant. The good news is that any sequence of n additions will take at most a constant times n steps.

Comment: @JimMischel but if we use two stacks instead of ArrayList for `elements` and `addedConstants` then we can truly get constant time assuming the stack is implemented with a list (which is usually the case)

Comment: @GustavoTorres but then how would you get the constant time update to arbitrary elements that you need in order to add to an arbitrary prefix?

Comment: @jacobm yes, I overlooked that. It is definitely better to get the amortized constant time. Even use dictionaries we will still just get amortized constant time

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a [Doubly Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) with maintaining a head and tail reference, as well as the current sum and count.

> Add the integer x to the first i elements of the sequence

Start at *head, add `x`, next item. Repeat `i` times. `sum += i*x`

> Append an integer k to the end of the sequence

Start at *tail, make new item with head = tail, tail = null. Update *tail, sum, and count accordingly.

> Remove the last element of the sequence

Update *tail to *tail->prev. Update sum, decrement count

> Retrieve the average 5.5 ([3, 8])

Return sum / count

Comment: +1  Although you could do this with a singly-linked list. No need for the double-link. Just keep the head and tail pointers.

Comment: Without a link to the previous element, removing the last element becomes O(n), right? Gotta know what to update *tail to

Comment: No, you need both -- you need to be able to find the next-to-last in constant time, and you need to be able to iterate across an arbitrary-size prefix in time proportional to the size of the prefix.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. Gotta have that back link to remove the last one.

Comment: "Repeat i times" is O(N), he said he needs sub linear.

Comment: @robertking yeah that was an edit after I answered. Honestly, I'm not sure that's even possible, to get better than `O(i)` for that operation at least. I don't understand what that would even mean

Comment: You can using a Binary Indexed Tree (log(n)). Other option is to answer multiple queries at once. E.g. if you have the following (i, x) pairs = (1,1), (2, 1), (3, 1), then you would go through and add 1, 2, 3 doing only 3 operations rather than doing 3+2+1 operations. (bad example but yeah).

Answer (score 1):

This data structure can just be a tuple (N, S) where N is the count and S is the sum and a stack of numbers.  Nothing fancy.  All operations are O(1) except for the first which is O(i).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try using a [Binary Indexed Tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees).

They allow you to access the cumulative frequency in O(Log(n)).

You can also add to the first i elements in order log(i).

However instead of increasing the first i elements by X, simply increase the n-ith element by X.

To remove the last element, perhaps have another tree which adds up how much as been cumulatively removed. (so instead of removing, you add that amount to another tree which you always subtract from your result when accessing the first tree).

For appending, I suggest you start with a tree of size 2*N
that will give you room. Then If you ever get larger than 2*N, add another tree of size 2*N. (not exactly sure on the best way to do this but hopefully you can figure it out).

Comment: So instead of increasing the first i elements by X, you increase the ith element by X*i? But what happens if that's the last element in the list, and then you remove it? You lose i*X, when you were really only supposed to lose X + whatever the last element was. The sum is then incorrect.

Comment: you increase the nth-i element by x. That increases the cumulative frequency for elements n-i, n-i+1, .. n by x. The actual sum is the sum of the cumulative frequencies, however it's O(1) if you keep track of it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy the first requirement, you can maintain a separate data structure of add operations. Basically, it's an ordered collection of ranges and increments. You also maintain the sum of those additions. So, if you added 5 to the first three items, and then added 12 to the first 10 items, you would have:

```
{3, 5}
{10, 12}
```

And the sum of those additions is `(3*5) + (10*12)` = 135.

When asked for the sum, you provide the sum of the items plus the sum of these additions.

The only trouble you have is when you remove the last item in the list. Then you have to go through this collection of additions to find any that include the last item (the one that you're removing). That data structure could be a hash map, with the key being the index. So in the example above, your hash map would be:

```
key: 3  value: 5
key: 10 value: 12
```

Whenever you do that first operation, you check the hash map to see if there's already an item with that key. If so, you just update the value there rather than adding a new increment. And update the sum accordingly.

Interesting. You don't even have to keep an extra sum of the additions. You can update the total sum while you're at it.

When you remove the last item from the list, you check the hash map for an item with that key. If there is one, you remove that item, decrease the key, and then add it back to the hash map (or update an existing item with that key, if there is one).

So, use the doubly-linked list proposed by mattedgod, with the sum as he proposed. And then use this hash map to maintain your collection of additions to the list, updating the sum accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The round #174 problem setters have published an editorial for this round. You can find it [here](http://www.codeforces.com/blog/entry/7036). Also you can take a look on some accepted solutions: [Python](http://www.codeforces.com/contest/283/submission/3346098), [C++](http://www.codeforces.com/contest/283/submission/3357635).

Comment: Of course the optimal solution here is O(1) for each operation. I could try to explain it more thoroughly, if you still don't understand, but I think the given solutions are quite simple.

Comment: I did read the tutorial but their explanation were not very clear for me, and most solutions code was quite cryptic. Although the python solution is very nice indeed